# Lodash forEach function won't line break yeoman generator integration

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, lodash, yeoman-generator

in my yeoman generator's index.js file I have this code snippet

```
this.fs.copyTpl(
    this.templatePath('/index2.html'),
    this.destinationPath('app/index2.html'), {
        title: [this.templatedata.test1, this.applicationName],
        h1: this.applicationName
    }
);
```

I am trying to run this lodash forEach statement in my html file and it won't line break no matter what I try.

```
<% _.forEach(title, function(title) { %><li><%- title %></li>\n<% }); %>
```

The result is:

```
<li>Star Wars!</li>\n<li>Foundation5Application</li>\n
```

What I expect is

```
<li>Star Wars!</li>
<li>Foundation5Application</li>
```

Is there anything I can do to correct this forEach statement?

Comment: Try `\\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: that didn't work because of how yeoman is procesing the template.  but the solution below worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an actual line break:

`<% _.forEach(title, function(title) { %><li><%- title %></li>
<% }); %>`